# How is assignments to compound literals useful?

Tags: c, gcc, lvalue, compound-literals

I was reading about compound literals, and I saw that they are l-values. So I suspected that you can assign them, so I did an experiment and I noticed that this compiles without warnings with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(void) {
    (struct foo){0,0} = (struct foo){1,1};
}
```

It got me confused, because I really cannot see any situation at all where this could be useful. When would you ever want to assign anything *to* a compound literal?

Or is it one of the usual undefined behaviors? Because it looks very much alike modifying string literals. This compiles without warnings with the same parameters as above:

```
struct foo *ptr = &(struct foo){0,0};
*ptr = (struct foo){1, 1};

char *str = "Hello";
*str = 'X'; // Undefined behavior
```

Modifying the string is undefined behavior according to [C standard 6.4.5.7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7)

Comment: It's a good thing to know if you are ever doing a pub quiz about C. Seems more like an emergent property than an intended feature.

Comment: Since when has C ever been in the habit of banning constructs merely because they are useless?

Comment: `(T0){0}=(T1){0}` can be used to "statically assert" that items of type `T1` can be assigned to items of type `T0`. Sometimes stuff like this is useful in some clever macro magic. The fewer-special-cases-in-the-language point is also good.

Comment: @PSkocik Nice one. Write an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it might not be *useful*, but it is the one that has *least restrictions*.

Since a non-const-qualified compound literal of non-array type **is** a modifiable lvalue, and modifiable lvalues can be assigned to among *all things* that you can do to modifiable lvalues, then you *can* assign to compound literals.

The opposite would be that you would have some *extra* cases for what you *cannot do* to lvalues that are compound literals.

---

I found out a use case for this that *would* work would assignment result in lvalue, which it doesn't:

Since you just a moment ago stated that yo do not like macros, then I am not sure if this is going to convince you, but this makes it possible to write a macro that expands to something like

```
foo(&((struct baz){0} = bar()))
```

here `bar` returns a `struct baz` as a value, and `foo` needs a pointer to such `struct` as an argument. Without this feature you cannot do such value passing inline.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's what one gets when not testing, I was *just* compiling this to get `error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`

Comment: Instead of striking out, can we have that part removed altogether?

Comment: @SouravGhosh why, someone else could spend time testing that :d

Answer (score 2):

*What is the goal of compound literals?*
The goal is to create a fully usable on the stack without providing a name for it.

*Does "fully usable object on the stack" entail being an lvalue?*
Yes. One of the typical uses for compound literals is to have their address taken and being passed on to some function. The goal is, that, whenever I have a function that takes a `Foo* fooPtr`, I can supply the argument as a compound literal `&(Foo){...}`. Since I'm taking the address and need to pass the non-const pointer on to the function, the compound literal must be an lvalue.

Note that the function can then assign to the object with a simple `*fooPtr = (Foo){...};`. Code like this is very typical for constructors, or functions that reset an object. The function does not know whether `fooPtr` points to a compound literal, a named variable, or a memory chunk on the heap. The assignment is legal for all these cases.

You see, the fact that you can assign to a compound literal is simply a side effect of compound literals being lvalues. And compound literals are only really useful as an inline, on-the-fly object creation construct if they are really lvalues.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any good use, but I did find some notable differences to string literals. The [chapter about compound literals](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5) only have one occurrence of the word "undefined" and as one can see, it's not applicable to assignments or other modifications in general:

> 16 Note that if an iteration statement were used instead of an explicit goto and a labeled statement, the lifetime of the unnamed object would be the body of the loop only, and on entry next time around p would have an indeterminate value, which would result in undefined behavior.

So the answer to "is it undefined behavior" seems to be: "No, it's not."

Furthermore, another difference is the lifetime. While string literals [always have static storage](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) compound literals do not:

> 5 The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block.

That would mean this is completely ok:

```
char *get_string() {
    return "Foobar"; // Ok! Static storage
}
```

But this is not:

```
struct my_struct {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct my_struct *get_my_struct() {
    return &(struct my_struct){0,0}; // Not ok! Automatic storage
}
```

I also made an experiment. I'm not 100% how to interpret it, because it could both be interpreted as static storage and undefined behavior. This outputted "42":

```
int main(void) {
    struct my_struct *p = get_my_struct();
    struct my_struct *t = get_my_struct();
    p->x = 42;
    printf("%d\n", t->x);
}
```

However, when I turned on `-O2` or `-O3` it printed "0" instead, so I'm pretty sure it's undefined behavior. Different results depending on optimization level is a very common symptom of UB. Note though that no warning was issued before I turned on optimization. When I did, I got this:

```
warning: ‘<Uf3f0>.x’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   16 |     printf("%d\n", t->x);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Another thing worth noting is this:

> 7 String literals, and compound literals with const-qualified types, need not designate distinct objects

Which would mean that two compound literals *without* const **should** designate *distinct* objects, but this is not true for string literals.

Answer (score -2):

IMO there is no reason of banning it even if it is not useful.

IMO very similar to the

```
void foo(void)
{
    int a = a;

    a = a;
}
```

Even `a` is considered as initialized by the compiler :)

https://godbolt.org/z/Msv6q9

Comment: `warning: variable 'a' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: `int a=a;` is more dangerous as that one's actually UB. Like with the compound literal example though where the assignment was allowed because of the modifiable-lvalue-ness of the compound literal (a property useful in other contexts), this too is an unintended consequence of a rule useful in other contexts--namely that the scoping rules of identifiers allow for things like circular linked-list heads to be statically initialized to point to themselves.